# AngularJS data binding and jQuery promises

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Inside my angular controller I have the following method defined

```
$scope.searchListing = function() {
    $http({
        url: App.Url.to('listing/feed/21312')
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
}
```

In view, $scope.data.listing is looped

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="property in data.listings"><!-- stuff --></div>
```

searchListing is triggered using ng-click and the things works perfectly. However I have a separate API which handles the API calls to my app, and it's based on jQuery. After integrating my jQuery based API

```
$scope.searchListing = function() {
    App.Listing.getListing().done(function(data){
        $scope.data = data;
    });
}
```

The API returns jqXHR objects so I can call promise methods on them. The problem is even though the data get assigned to $scope.data my view doesn't get updated. After the ajax request completed I accessed the controller to check if data got assigned

```
angular.element('[ng-controller=listingController]').scope().data
```

And it did show the data, why doesn't the view get updated?

Comment: have a lot easier time using angular `$http` or `$resource` since scope already accepts promises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When data in the Angular model (`$scope`), changes, Angular recognizes this and triggers a digest loop which re-renders the view with the updated data.

However, when this data change happens in a callback that is outside of Angular's viewport, Angular is unable to monitor the change. This is happening in your case where the data change is happening in a jQuery promise, which is not part of Angular. In this case, you need to manually trigger the digest loop like this:

```
App.Listing.getListing().done(function(data){
        $scope.data = data;

        // make sure your app is not currently in a digest loop
        if (!$scope.$$phase)
            $scope.$apply(); // trigger digest loop
});
```

Comment: Thank you!, side question, is it a good practise to use APIs like this inside controllers? or should I create a service to abstract things?

Comment: You should create Angular services for this. That's that they exist for, and that way, you don't need to worry about triggering the digest loop. Also, no reason to bind your Angular app so tightly to jQuery.

Comment: Unfortunately jQuery part is some thing already built so I have to stick to that, I tried creating a service http://pastie.org/7468663 and end up with the same result, do I still to trigger digest loop?

Comment: I guess I have to, triggered it out of $rootScope and it worked